# How to reset redo hot key in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

How to reset redo hot key in windows 10? The redo hot key is currently `Ctrl Y` in my system but I'd like to change it to `Ctrl Shift Z`.

I have checked some [links1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/undo-and-redo-shortcuts-ctrl-z-and-ctrl-y-not/d7567ebc-43a5-4ca2-979f-4fac5bf6d6d4), [links2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-it-possible-to-change-the-keyboard-shortcut-for/b5aff878-8ccb-4576-ac4f-dd5fabeeac79). Maybe I'm doing it wrong but they just don't seem to work.

In [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_2016/redo-shortcut-ctrly-vs-ctrlshiftz/1f54bd68-fcfa-4fa6-a725-daf4a4821d2d) it suggests customise hot key using `EditRedoOrRepeat`:
[image]

Where is `EditRedoOrRepeat`?

Additional info: I use multiple input languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right-click anywhere on the ribbon and click "Customize the ribbon..."[image]
2. At the bottom, click the button next to "Keyboard shortcuts" that says "Customize". [image]
3. You can then scroll down to All commands and follow the instructions you referenced.

Comment: Hi Quetza, thanks for the answer. It worked in Word; I'm wondering if you happen to know a way to apply it to the entire system? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to apply it to the whole system, you can use Autohotkey (https://www.autohotkey.com/). It's very easy to have Ctrl-Shift-Z do the same thing as Ctrl-Y, but is it necessary that Ctrl-Y doesn't do the default action?

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing the resource guess I'm quite used to Ctrl-Shift-Z

Comment: Makes sense, Ctrl-Shift-Z is easier to press. This should do it in Autohotkey: `^+z::^y`